# How to make always visible scroll in HTML 5?

Tags: css

I have enormous table to render on website. I need to make it scroll horizontally. Normally I would set fixed `width` and `overflow: scroll` but not in this case. The table is pretty tall so I don't see scroll at the bottom of web browser.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cpmjng5b/1/embedded/result/

I could set fixed `height` but I have text before table that height is dynamic.

http://jsfiddle.net/cpmjng5b/5/embedded/result/

What should I do? Try to calculate `div.container` height in JS? I already tried [floating scroll plugin](http://amphiluke.github.io/jquery-plugins/floatingscroll/) for jQuery but it is relatively slow. Can I make it in pure css somehow?

Comment: can you set a max height to the container or the table?

Comment: Yes, I can but the table is going to be higher than max height always I guess.

Comment: I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/cpmjng5b/6/ - is that what you are after?

Comment: @blurfus It is not working as expected. See floating scroll plugin mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is using jquery, but you could also do it with javascript.

1. Calculate the height of your window and subtract the height of the dynamic text.
2. Take that number and make it the max-height of your div surrounding the table.

The height in the fiddle is a little off due to the jsfiddle "Result" header, but you can add/subtract any additional pixels if you have a top navigation.

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
var topcontentHeight = $(".dynamicText").height();
$(".container").css("max-height", (viewportHeight - topcontentHeight) + 'px');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7v7nhmnj/3/embedded/result/)

Comment: On small screen it could even set table height to negative property, anyway the container can get very small at times. I would like solution like `floating scroll plugin` mentioned in the question but in pure HTML5. I don't care about old browsers.